# Menus desaparecidos en visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Al dar clic derecho en la carpeta de Scripts o cualquier otra, no aparecen los menus de agregar Archivo JavaScript, Hoja de Estilos, etc...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solo me sucede en este proyecto, en los otros los tengo sin pronblema.

Asi es como deberia estar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Saben como solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Procura abrir el visual studio como administrador, y por cierto si le tienes el play o run al visual studio no te dejara ni modificar los nombres de los archivos.

Comment: si utilizas el item Nuevo elemento...